# How to enable service installation event (event id 4697) in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, audit

In windows 10, after I use the following command to enable `Security System Extension`:

```
auditpol /set /subcategory:"Security System Extension" /success:enable /failure:disable
```

Whenever a new service is added, the system generates Event ID 4697, indicating "A service was installed in the system." This event is particularly useful because it includes the client process ID that initiated the creation of the service.

How can I activate Event ID 4697 on Windows 7?

Comment: Windows 7 was end of life four years ago and is off topic in this forum.

Comment: Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault. A Dead Horse is a dead Horse, because a dead horse....... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-10/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4697 :

Based on MSDN:

> Minimum OS Version: Windows Server 2016, Windows 10.